# How to get a list data that are in global environment into a list

Tags: r

I am working on a list of .csv data which I have read in and keep the variables that i need for study. During this process, I have build multiple data set with name xxx_101(PY_101, vB_101_FG_101, etc.) which store in global environment. Now I want to put every new data set with ending _101 into a list. Is it a clever way to build that list other than type them in one by one? Once I read them in to a list, I would like to rename the each list with their original data name. Is there a easy way to do that?

I could do it one by one, but just feel there should be a better way to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` with `ls` and specify the `pattern` with `"_101"` as the end (`$`) of the object name.  It would get the values of all those objects into a `list`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "_101$"))
```